# I am having trouble installing Linux Mint (Gnu/Linux)

Tags: boot-loader

sorry just frustrated. My machine is the Dell Inspiron Mini 1012 with Intel Atom N450 @ 1.7-GHz on GMA 3150 (no NVIDIA Graphics) and Legacy BIOS (only). It runs on 32-bits Architecture, 2MB of RAM. The mainboard is PC2-5300 (800-MHz) DDR2 SODIMM and a 250-GB HDD.

My problem is a system & keyboard freeze after (& later, during) install of LM Mate (and/or tried all versions) 19.2. No Operating System error-message and no internet (firefox), even thought the Ethernet downloaded the software during installation.

Now, the computer just won’t boot the LM OS. I’m having many issues with this OS (unlike Windows). I would appreciate the help because after I sampled (a little) LM 19 (can’t use 19.2), it maybe better (don’t really know, yet). I tried some of LM troubleshooting online, but the solution did not make any sense (how can you fix something without the system installed correctly (no terminal access to failed installation) and without internet. If LM was as simple to install as Microsoft windows, I think I would choose LM; but in America you pay for what you get, I guess!?!?

So, as a newbie with too many questions, how can I fix the

- LM OS can’t boot,
- the freezes,
- no internet in that order.

Help ME, I been working on this for 6 months.

Comment: What's LM?  If it's "Linux Mint", it would help if you spelled it out and tagged the question appropriately (and also properly formatted the text into paragraphs, and added a more informative title). Have you successfully run "LM" on the machine before? Have you been able to run any other Linux on the same machine? Have you tested the RAM modules with some form of memory checker for errors?

Comment: Along with what @Kusalananda asked for, is this a dual-boot system? Also, you may want to try an older version of Mint, maybe get the 18.3 32-bit ISO. The kernels used by newer OS's may not work with older hardware.

Comment: And proof read: I suspect some of the info is incorrect (you probably just typed the wrong thing). You will also have to tell us more about the No Operating System error-message. When does it appear?, what does it look like?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to investigate Lubuntu for 32 bit platforms.

Download the ISO and burn it to a DVD.

See info at https://docs.lubuntu.net/lubuntu_installation_on_old_computers

See downloads at https://lubuntu.net/downloads/

Ken